# React - add values to autosuggest dynamically

Tags: reactjs

There is input `position` in my form, `onKeyUp` script sends

```
handlePositionKeyUp(e) {

        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://example.com/suggests/positions/?text='+e.target.value, 
            headers: { 
                'User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
            })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }
```

`response` contains `data`, `data` contains array `items` and every `items` has field `name`. Is it possible to get all `names` from `response` and  dynamically create  autosuggest for this input?

Comment: so based on the input filter the responses?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question either

Comment: I would like to get all `text` from `items` http://prntscr.com/itf8cm and dynamically create list of autosuggests for my input and render it on the page

Comment: ok everything makes sense but what does autosuggests mean, is your input a select with options? or is it an actualy input that takes text

Comment: Maybe something like HTML5 `datalist` element https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_list.asp. To get values, to create `datalist` and add it after input on page.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
handlePositionKeyUp(e) {
    if(e.target.value.length > 1) {

        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://example.com/suggests/positions/?text='+e.target.value, 
            headers: { 
                'User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)', 
                'HH-User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)',  
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
            })
          .then(function (response) {
            var positionsList = document.createElement('datalist');
            positionsList.setAttribute("id","positions-list");

            var positionsListInner = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.items.length; i++) {
               positionsListInner += "<option value='"+ response.data.items[i].text +"'>";    
            }

            positionsList.innerHTML = positionsListInner;

            var el = document.getElementById("positions-list");
            if (el) {
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }

            var posWrap = document.getElementById('position-wrap');
            posWrap.appendChild(positionsList);

          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    } 
}
```

it's not very beautiful, bit it works.